# GCP Notebook Instance: Error 524 unable to open Jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-ml

I am currently new to the GCP ecosystem. Over the past week, I have successfully created a notebook instance and have been using it. However, recently I encounter an issue whereby I am unable to open jupyter lab. Upon looking at the health status (image below). I realise the Juypter Lab API Status and Jupyterlab status are unhealthy.

Things I have tried and did not work:

- Restarting the notebook instance
- Restarting the Jupyter API
- Restarting the Docker

Wondering if anyone has faced similar issues before? Any guidance on fixing this would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

[Notebook Health Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7f1S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the troubleshooting 'diagnostic tool' as mentioned here:
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/troubleshooting#opening_a_notebook_results_in_a_524_a_timeout_occurred_error ?

Take a look at the output log of it and it might give you some hint what is the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes I did follow the troubleshooting guidelines. Didn't seem to work. Currently using a workaround by just creating a new VM instance instead. Issue has not yet surfaced.